# Python - Convert particular columns of data to integer

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that is stored with NumPy. Is it possible to only convert the first and second columns to integers from float?

**This is my example of a 2d array.**

[image: 2D array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asType()` method

```
import numpy as np

arrayOfFloats = np.array(
    [
        [1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
        [4.3, 5.4, 6.2]
    ]
)

arrayOfFloats[0:1, 0:2] = arrayOfFloats[0:1, 0:2].astype(np.int64)

print(arrayOfFloats)
```